# How to install wso2 microgateway 3.2.7 on Docker Desktop

Tags: wso2-micro-gateway

I am following the guide https://mg.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/install-on-docker/, to install wso2 microgateway 3.2.7 on my docker desktop on windows 10, and I have the following result::

```
PS C:\wso2\mgw-petstore> micro-gw build petstore --deployment-config .\petstore\conf\deployment.toml
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
Generating sources...[DONE]
Compiling source
        wso2/petstore:3.2.0


Creating balos
        target\balo\petstore-2020r1-java8-3.2.0.balo

Running Tests

        wso2/petstore:3.2.0
        No tests found


Generating executables
        target\bin\petstore.jar

Generating docker artifacts...
error [docker plugin]: module [wso2/petstore:3.2.0] unable to build docker image: connection refused to docker host

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Target: "C:\wso2\mgw-petstore\petstore\target\petstore.jar"
```

As you can see, the generation of the JAR file is successful and it only fails in the last step of generating the docker image, I don't know why I have this error:

***error [docker plugin]: module [wso2/petstore:3.2.0] unable to build docker image: connection refused to docker host***

The docker images in my local environment are:

[image: Docker images]

Can you help me, please